# How do I change the default rustc / Cargo linker?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, lld

I would like to make rustc use `lld` as a linker instead of `ld` in a particular crate. So I create `.cargo/config` in my project directory with the following:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]                                                                   
linker = "ld.lld"
```

Which leads to linker errors:

```
$ cargo build
...
  = note: ld.lld: error: unable to find library -ldl
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lrt
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lpthread
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc_s
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lm
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lrt
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lpthread
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lutil
          ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lutil
```

Same thing with `rust-lld`. If I set `linker = "ld"` (which should be the default, right?), I just get

```
  = note: ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

I tried to resolve all the missing libraries manually (with `-C link-arg=--library-path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and the like), but it only lead to wrong linkage and a segfaulting binary.

Interestingly enough, if I replace `/usr/bin/ld` with a symlink to `/usr/bin/ld.lld`, it works great (no errors, and from the compiled binary I see that it was indeed linked with `lld`). However, I don't want to make `lld` my system-wide linker, I just want to use it in a particular Rust crate.

So what is the proper way to change the default rustc linker?

Comment: What happens if you put `clang` as the linker?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Thanks to @Jmb comment, I found a solution. Turns out that the default linker that `rustc` uses is actually `cc` (which makes sense - it supplies all the needed defaults to compile/link C code, which also work for Rust). We can pass an argument to `cc` to make it link with `lld`:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld",
]
```

Now `cargo build` links with `lld`.

Answer (score 9):

Adding this to `.cargo/config.toml` (in the project) forces using lld

```ini
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = ["-C", "linker=clang", "-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]
```

For more information see this:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71515

You can remove `"-C", "linker=clang"` on Linux, if you have Gcc 9 or newer installed

Comment: I don't think this has any effect if it's placed in the Cargo.toml.  It should go into the config file instead:  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Answer (score 5):

This also works and is what I think @Jmb actually asked.

```
rustflags = [
  "-C", "linker=clang-12",  # change the version as needed
]
```