# How to compile rust with specific specific C++ compiler

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-cargo

I have a build in an isolated environment that does not have a C++ compiler in PATH.  How can I dynamically specify the C++ compiler for cargo to use (for ex: by environment variable)?

It seems as though this is possible, but none of the solutions I've seen appear to match [the environment variable docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) or in the Cargo.toml [`[target]` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies).

Comment: [`target.<triple>.linker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#targettriplelinker), maybe?

Comment: Do you want to build rust itself? If not, what C++ packages are you trying to build?

Comment: @trentcl, isn't that only for the linker not the compiler?

Comment: @HHK, both windows toolchains/targets for rust require a C++ compiler under the hood.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need a C++ compiler to build Rust programs on Windows. The only reason you need Visual C++ Build Tools (on msvc) is for the linker. But I don't personally run on Windows, so I really don't know.

Comment: @trentcl when I target gnu, it requires g++.exe instead of MSVC tools (ex: link.exe).  Is g++.exe just used for linking as well?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're confused about -- in some (most?) cases the "linker" actually *is* a compiler, which is not used to compile but just as a frontend to supply the correct system-specific arguments to the actual linker (as also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57812916/3650362)). If you tell it to use a "mere" linker you might need to provide those arguments yourself -- at least, that's how it works on Linux.